# How do you filter a url for certain JSON key values?

Tags: ruby, json, filter

I am currently loading in a url, parsing it in Ruby, and then iterating a select and map method over the entire array to extract certain data. This can take longer, and slows down the front end if I'm querying every minute (which is what I'm doing). Is there a way to do this at the url request, to sort of 'pre-filter' the json array so that I'm not querying every single item, every single time?

My current select/map method works like this:

```
>> request and parse some url into json 'array'

array_filtered = array['orders'].select { |h| h['updated_at'] > $time_min }.map { |order| order['order_number'] }
```

This is taking a specified time, $time_min in ISO8601, and checking and pulling out every item in the array with an 'updated_at' key value greater than the $time_min. 
Is it possible to do this string comparison in the url?

-Thanks

Comment: Is the data changing this often? I.e. every time (each minute) you call the URL you get different data?

Comment: Also what is the URL you are calling? Is it an API endpoint? Doesn't it have any documentation?

Comment: hi, yes the data is rolling in rather rapidly and it goes into an API on woocommerce (wc-api/v3/)

Comment: Unless the API you're querying to get the data has some filtering mechanism, I think you're doing it the best way you can. In order to avoid slowing down the front end, I'd look at the possibility of using a socket connection to stream the data instead of requesting it at interval.

Comment: okay, I will look into that as I've not used it before. Thanks for the tip!